# Pyspark dataframes alternative function to colSums() in R

Tags: pyspark

Do you know the alternative to R function colSums() in Pyspark for dataframes? I would like to convert this:

```
colSums(is.na(dataset))
```

Comment: jop it looks like the same thing, could mark as duplicate